# Modify persistent variables on a remote server host using 'ssh' from client host

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables, remote-connection

As the title says, I want to modify environment variables on a remote server using 'ssh'.

My first attempt was:

```
$ ssh mysvr -l sikaiwei "getId=$ORANGE; echo $ORANGE; ORANGE=$((ORANGE+1)); echo $ORANGE; echo 'getId is '+$getId;"
```

At first, I didn't define $ORANGE on the server host,
but defined $ORANGE as "1" on the client, and I got:

```
1
1
getId is +
```

Note that the command is picking up the client's value of $ORANGE,
and the update (`ORANGE+1`) isn't happening.

Then I removed the $ORANGE definition on the client host,
and defined $ORANGE on the server by putting a command into my `.bash_profile`.
But

```
$ ssh mysvr -l sikaiwei "getId=$ORANGE; echo $ORANGE; ORANGE=$((ORANGE+1)); echo $ORANGE; echo 'getId is '+$getId;"
```

resulted in

```
getId is +
```

It can't print the value of $ORANGE that I attempted to initialize on the server host!
Then I tried this:

```
$ ssh mysvr -l sikaiwei ". .profile; getId=$ORANGE; echo $ORANGE; ORANGE=$((ORANGE+1)); echo $ORANGE; echo 'getId is '+$getId;"


getId is +
```

It still doesn't work.

I tried using '..' (single quotes) instead ".." (double quotes) as you said,
but it prints nothing...

```
$ ssh myth@mysvr 'echo orangeis $ORANGE'
orangeis
```

I want to print

```
 getId=1; echo 1; ORANGE=2; echo 2; …
```

instead of

```
 getId=; echo ; ORANGE=1; echo ; …
```

So how can I use the $ORANGE value from the server host instead of the client value?

My server machine runs Windows, but I installed Cygwin.
My client machine runs Linux.

**Edit:** I found part of the problem: I was setting $ORANGE in `~/.bash_profile` on the server host, and I can get value of $ORANGE using "echo $ORANGE" in an interactive shell (Cygwin), but this wasn't affecting `ssh` command strings.
For example, I get nothing when my client host uses

```
$ ssh sikaiwei@mysvr 'echo orange is $ORANGE'
orange is
```

Like that, I don't get the value of $ORANGE that I do in a session on the server.
The **`. .profile`** that I added didn't help.
But if I

```
$ ssh sikaiwei@mysvr '. ~/.bash_profile;echo orange is $ORANGE'
orange is 4
```

I got the value!

---

Oh, did I forget to mention: I want these variables on the server to be persistent.
In other words, if I execute an `ssh` command that changes the value of $ORANGE from 4 to 42, then I want $ORANGE to be 42 when I do another `ssh` command.

Comment: You say, “I … defined $ORANGE on the server host.” How? What did you do to define ORANGE on the server?

Comment: Server machine is mine.It run Windows,but installed Cygwin.I definde ORANGE in .bash_profile on the Server.

Comment: Are you sure `.bash_profile` gets processed for `ssh` jobs? Can you check by putting `echo $ORANGE` into `.bash_profile`?

Comment: My fault...First I use `. ~/.bash_profile`,then I can use the variable defined in `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Well, the [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) man page says that `bash` reads `.bash_profile` only if it is an interactive shell, or if it is invoked with the `--login` option. If you invoke `ssh` with a command string argument, the shell will not be considered interactive, and so `.bash_profile` will not be read automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that shell variables
(of which environment variables are a subset or variant)
that are quoted in double quotes (`"…"`) are processed immediately. 
So, if `ORANGE` is set to 1 locally,
*as you report having done in your first experiment*,
and you type

```
… ssh … "getId=$ORANGE; echo $ORANGE; ORANGE=$((ORANGE+1)); echo $ORANGE; …"
```

`ssh` is getting

```
getId=1; echo 1; ORANGE=2; echo 1; …
```

And, if `ORANGE` is not set locally,
*as you report having done in your second experiment*, `ssh` is getting

```
getId=; echo ; ORANGE=1; echo ; …
```

To send the command to the remote system as you typed it, complete with dollar signs,
so it will be processed by the shell on the remote system,
wrap it in single quotes (`'…'`).

For example, if you say

```
… ssh … 'echo orangeis $ORANGE'
```

then `ssh` is seeing

```
echo orangeis $ORANGE
```

and sending that to the remote system. 
This causes the shell on the remote system to output

```
orangeis
```

(with a space at the end) because you haven’t done anything to give `ORANGE` a value
(or, if you did something, it didn’t work).

You say

> I  want to print
>
> ```
>   getId=1; echo 1; ORANGE=2; echo 1; …
> ```

which is clearly not what you mean. 
If you mean that you want to print

```
getId=1
1
2
  ︙
```

try something like

```
… ssh … 'ORANGE=1; getId="$ORANGE"; echo "getId=$getId"; echo $ORANGE; ORANGE=$((ORANGE+1)); echo $ORANGE; …"
```

---

You have refined your question (in the comments) to indicate that you want to be able to manipulate shell/environment variables on the remote server ***and have changed values persist from one session to another***. To do this, you will need to explicitly store the values somewhere (on the server).
A simple way to save a value is to execute

```
echo "$ORANGE" > orange.txt
```

You can then retrieve this value with a command like

```
read ORANGE < orange.txt
```

or

```
ORANGE=$(cat orange.txt)
```

A slightly different approach would be to save your value with

```
echo "ORANGE=\"$ORANGE\"" > value.sh
```

and then retrieve it with

```
. value.sh
```

IMNSHO, it doesn’t particularly make sense to use your `.bash_profile` to store these values if you are going to modify them on a frequent basis.

Note that you should use `>>` to append to a file and `>|` to overwrite an existing file.

Comment: I reedit it.If like last line of your answer ,when a new ssh chonnection start ,it can't get the value of ORANGE defined at first ssh connection,So I want to defined a System variable which every ssh connection can access and modify dynamics.Look at the end of question ,I use '. .~/.bash_profile' ,then get the value.

Comment: Shell variables are transient. If you type `PURPLE=17` or `ZAPHOD=42` to a shell, and then logout and login again, those values will be gone.  Similarly, separate `ssh` sessions are ***separate*** (e.g., if you do `ssh cd /foo` and then do another `ssh` command, you’ll be back in your home directory – shell state isn’t preserved across sessions). But see my answer for more information.

Comment: Sorry for waste your time to reedit my quedtion and answer it...And thanks a lot!The answer is my want!